# Get the number of elements of an array passed by parameter in C?

Tags: c

Can someone help me figure this out?

I think this is not possible... Unless i pass another parameter with the size? I'm looking to avoid it.

How could I do this?

```
int size(int *array){
    return (sizeof(array) / sizeof(int));
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int array[] = {1,2,3,4};

    printf("%d", size(array) );

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not do that as a function. You can do it as a macro though.

```
#define SIZEOF_ARRAY(array) (sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array))
```

Comment: Every C programmer writes that macro.  Naming choices are interesting, haven't seen your version before.  Please ignore the moron that voted you down, good answer.

Comment: You should add that this only works on arrays *before* they decay to a pointer to the first element; that's not obvious to C newbies. (Although neither is array decay.)

Comment: Minor: Consider   `printf("%u", SIZEOF_ARRAY(array) )` or `printf("%zu", SIZEOF_ARRAY(array) )`.

Comment: I'm curious, why can't SIZEOF_ARRARY be implemented as a function?

Comment: Because an array name decays into a pointer, when passed as an argument to a function.

Comment: Ah, so sizeof(ptr) would be the size of the pointer, which is not right.